# Configuring QGIS to show only toolbars wanted?

Tags: qgis, toolbar, gui

I friend of mine asked me a question the other day that I didn't knew the answer to. In his organization, they are using QGIS for non GIS-experienced people. He would like to configure QGIS to only show the tools/toolbar that those non-experienced people need to see. A common complaint is that QGIS looks too so difficult with all toolbars. QGIS is installed to this users on a server and he would like to control this so that people don't need to change the toolbars on every computer that are using QGIS.

How can I solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 3):

Sure thing. Using the latest build (soon to be 1.8) you can use the method described here http://linfiniti.com/2011/07/customizing-the-qgis-ui/

You can turn every part of ui on or off using Settings -> Customization...

Answer (score 3):

Going into a little more depth than Nathan's answer, the actual changes themselves are stored within QGIS in the following locations (Operating system dependent):

- Linux it is found in:  `~/.config/QuantumGIS/QGIS.conf`
- Windows: the registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QuantumGIS\QGIS`
- Mac:  `~/Library/Preferences/org.qgis.QGIS.plist`

That's for 1.7.x, but may also apply to 1.8.x (which is still a development build so you may not wish to be deploying corporately yet)