# qgis toolbars revert to default positions on re-opening application

Tags: qgis, toolbar, gui

On my PC and most of my users, we can move the toolbars into their optimal positions for our purposes, save and close the application, and they are still there on re-opening, as you would wish.

However, for a small minority of users, this is not working, and on re-opening, the toolbars are reverting to their default positions when we re-open the application.

Any ideas? I looked at an ini customisation file, but they don't contain data that determines the positions of toolbars, so I don't think there is a solution there.

We are currently on the 2.8.2 Wien LTR.

Comment: This [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24138/configure-qgis-to-show-only-the-toolbars-wanted?rq=1) contains an answer which mentions where the UI settings are saved for different platforms. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Could it be that the location where the settings should be saved (see the answers to the [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24143/51574) mentioned by Joseph) isn't writable by the affected user?